# Subexpression in regular expression Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

Why do we need a subexpression in regular expressions in Oracle?

It is new feature of Oracle 11g, we can specify which subexpression from pattern we want to find. We can use this parameter in `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and `REGEXP_INSTR`.

Here is an example from docs:

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('1234567890', '(123)(4(56)(78))', 1, 1, 0, 'i', 2) 
"REGEXP_INSTR" FROM DUAL;

REGEXP_INSTR
-------------------
4
```

But it isn't clear to me, why do we really need this parameter (in the above example we could just use `4(56)(78)` pattern). Does anyone have real-world example?

Comment: I think that is to get a specific group on that regular expression pattern. I don't know why it is called subexpression when this concept is well known as group. So for this pattern (123)(4(56)(78)) there are 4 groups 1=123, 2=4, 3=56 and 4=78 each set of parenthesis determine a group. I didn't add it as an answer because I can't remember an example of use but it is needed for sure!

Comment: @JorgeCamposyes, yep, this is groups. But in docs they call it `subexpression` in pattern. Don't know why. I almost understand why we need it. Just maybe someone could provide good real-world example...

Comment: Read this tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html Grouping and capturing groups in regepx is very huge topic. Oracle regexp implementation is limited, for example you cannot use back- and -forward references in the pattern itself, but can be used in REGEXP_REPLACE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle regex does not support [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Just like `^` and `$` anchors can be used to specify start and end of the string, lookarounds(lookbehind/lookahead) can be used to match(or not) any pattern either preceding or succeeding the pattern that you are interested in.

For example consider the following values in a column and you need to select pickup date only.

```
event_dte
----------------------
pickup_dte 2015-04-03
shipped_dte 2015-03-02
PU_dte 2015-03-11
pickup_date 2014-05-02
delivery_dte 2015-07-11
```

There are all possible dates in this and the wording of pickup date is also not consistent.

You can write a regex like `(pickup|PU)_d(a?)te (\d{4}-]d{2}-\d{2})`. This will match the entire string and when used in regexp_substr will return entire string.
If you use subexpressions you can extract only the date part. For the above example, it will be third sub expression.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured that out, so if someone interested in that is my answer:

We use subexpression when we want to find a specific string, which follows some string, which also could follows some string etc. (or otherwise, find a string, which followed by some strings)

So for upper example I modify source string:

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('456781234567890', '(123)(4(56)(78))', 1, 1, 0, 'i', 2) 
"REGEXP_INSTR" FROM DUAL;

REGEXP_INSTR
-------------------
9
```

Here we will find position of string `45678` only if it follows `123`. And we get 9 instead of 1